# Linq to SQL Left Outer Join Not

Tags: sql, linq, outer-join

I have two Tables "Employees" and "EmployeesCompanies", Employees contains a list of all employees, and employeescompanies contains a list of all companies associated with an employee:

```
Table 1 (Employees)
EmployeeID
1
2
3

Table 2 (EmployeesCompanies)
EmployeeID    
1
2
```

I want to return 
3 which is the missing record from EmployeesCompanies, here is the linq code I'm using:

```
var queryOrphanedEmployees = (from a in db.Employees
join b in db.EmployeesCompanies
on a.EmployeeID equals b.EmployeeID
into outer
from c in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { a.EmployeeID}).ToList();
```

However this returns:

```
1
2
```

Which is exactly opposite to what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this if you've set up the foreign keys properly

```
from e in Employees
where !e.EmployeesCompanies.Any()
select e
```